# Connecting to the internet from a subnet

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I'm new to networking. I have a couple single-board computers (NanoPi NEOs running Armbian) on a subnet that I would like to connect to the internet. My laptop (which runs Ubuntu) is connected to an unmanaged switch, which is attached to my SBCs, using ethernet. My laptop also has a wireless connection to my home router. [Here's a diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS51O.png)

Right now, I can:

- ssh into the SBC from my laptop
- ping my laptop from the SBC
- ping my router from my laptop
- connect to the internet from my laptop

But I can't:

- ping google.com from a SBC
- ping any other computers on the 192.168.0.0 network from a SBC
- install software from the internet, using apt-get for example

Here is the /etc/network/interfaces file on the SBC:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# Network is managed by Network manager
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
#no-auto-down eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1
```

Here is the output from ifconfig on my SBC:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::7cb3:e4ff:fe0f:310e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7e:b3:e4:0f:31:0e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 930  bytes 83194 (81.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 770  bytes 99474 (97.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 35  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 22  bytes 1940 (1.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22  bytes 1940 (1.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is the output from ifconfig on my laptop:

```
enx0000bab02f0c: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::6ba:f0f:6e4:e4d5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:00:ba:b0:2f:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 426  bytes 58989 (58.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 634  bytes 59439 (59.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2751  bytes 211271 (211.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2751  bytes 211271 (211.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::c439:1ed9:4faa:5a3f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:a4:71:d4:37:c1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1711728  bytes 2313530817 (2.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 367535  bytes 57661749 (57.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I've tried googling, but I'm unable to find anything that works. I played around with the static routing option on my router, but also wasn't able to find anything that helped (because I don't know what I'm doing). Is what I want to do possible using static routing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just looked at your network diagram, to make that work you would have to make your laptop the gateway for the SBCs.(Making the wired interface the gate and then route the traffic out the wireless interface. Not the easiest task if you are new to this. The easier way to do this is download the packages to your laptop, scp them over to the SBC's and work that way. It's the far simpler solution. It's the minutes versus hours approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working. This page helped: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing.

Basically, what you have to do is run nm-connection-editor on your Ubuntu laptop, and then select the IPv4 Settings tab, then set the method to 'Shared to other computers'. Then, I clicked Add, and made Address '192.168.2.1' (the address of my laptop on the subnet), Netmask 24, and Gateway blank.